# Matrix total for every page in SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix which has more than 100 row records. I want to display per page total in matrix(not at matrix end total) like given below in image, but didn't get any solution. Is there any solution to do it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: There's probably a better way but I'd use a Row_Number in my source proc and set it to a specified number of rows. In your image it would be 3, So there would be a column that shows Milk,bread and soya as 1 then the next 3 as 2. In the report I'd then group on this column and add a total after each group. This will also allow you to page break after and specify how many items per page.

Comment: waah pandey!! kya question hai

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is:

1. Add a field rowcounter in your dataset that has rownumbers for each datarow
2. Create a Row group on your matrix with a rowcounter something like 
   Group on:Ceiling(Fields!rCounter.Value/x) 
   where x is the number of rows you want to adjust in the page
3. Create a total row or a group footer.
4. Force a page break on the group 
   In page break options : Between instance of each group.

Let me know if this solution works for you else I will create a POC to help.